# How to extract binary data from batch file using findstr command?

Tags: loops, batch-file, binary, findstr

I use the below batch script which has binary part (.exe program) append to the bottom of the script. I used this trick to attach binary part to my batch script:

```
::Append binary part to your batch file with COPY
copy /y /a "batchscript.bat" + /b program.exe /b combined.bat
```

In order to extract the binary part from the batch script (combined.bat), I use the following method with "findstr" command:

```
;;;===,,, @ECHO OFF
;;;===,,, SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
;;;===,,, 
;;;===,,, echo test line1
;;;===,,, echo test line2
;;;===,,, 
;;;===,,, findstr /v "^;;;===,,," %~f0 > program.exe
;;;===,,, 
;;;===,,, echo test line3
;;;===,,, echo test line4
;;;===,,, exit /b
;;;===,,, ::Below are binary data for program.exe
binarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinary
binarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinary
...
```

So this piece of code extracts the binary part from the script to program.exe:

```
findstr /v "^;;;===,,," %~f0 > program.exe
```

But as a down-side, each line of the script part must begin with following prefix

```
;;;===,,,
```

What I want to do is to use the prefix ";;;===,,," only at the last line of code and extract all binary data after this line. Is it possible to achieve this via some crazy combination of findstr + for loop + if command? Example:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

echo test line1
echo test line2

HERE IS THE CODE TO EXTRACT BINARY PART AFTER LAST SCRIPT LINE

echo test line3
echo test line4
exit /b
;;;===,,, ::Below are binary data for program.exe
binarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinary
binarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinarybinary
...
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get the line number of the dividing line
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^;;;===,,," "%~F0"') do set "lines=%%a"

rem Extract the binary part from this file
< "%~F0" (

   rem Pass thru the first lines
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%lines%) do set /P "="

   rem Copy the rest
   findstr "^"

) > program.exe
goto :EOF

;;;===,,, ::Below are binary data for program.exe
```

This program is *functionally equivalent* to your code, that is, this program will fail when your program fails. You should know that `findstr` command can *not* successfully copy binary data in all cases.

This solution makes good use of the fact that `findstr` command does not move the file pointer of the redirected input file that is leaved at the right place from the previous `set /P` commands.

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately your solution does not work. The script get stuck and show error messages (FINDSTR: Line XXXX is too long.), I need to end it with ctrl+break. 
The file program.exe is created partially, however its data does not match the binary data in the batch file. So your code does skip the first script lines, but the binary data are not copied correctly. It's strange when both codes are functionally equivalent, because my "findstr" code works fine on the same batch script and same binary data.

Comment: Ops! I just realized that when `findstr` command read lines from redirected input, the max. length is limited to 8KB, so both methods are _not_ equivalent! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman) for further details.